# Ubuntu server 16.04 hangs at random for no reason

Tags: server, freeze

I am running a Bitbucket server in a Virtual machine over Ubuntu 16.04 server edition.

After the server starts, it runs for a while and suddenly stops responding. Doesn't let me in through SSH or directly through console (vmware console). I look into the CPU/Memory/Disk/Network utilizations to see if there is any abnormality leading up to the issue, but find nothing (CPU util is less than 35%, Memory util is less than 25%, disk and nw also seem pretty normal. 
I looked into kernel log, syslog and don't find anything suspicious or any errors/warnings (except a couple of ntp unreachable errors that occur when the server was running).

I also go into the application (bitbucket) logs, but find nothing alarming there either.

At the moment, I am clueless on how to even debug the issue. Any pointers that you can think of?

Edit: Adding memory details as requested:

```
$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            15G        2.7G         11G        852K        951M         12G
Swap:          975M          0B        975M

$ swapon --show
NAME      TYPE      SIZE USED PRIO
/dev/dm-1 partition 976M   0B   -2
```

Comment: How much RAM? How much swap? `free -h;swapon --show`. Edit ( https://askubuntu.com/posts/1105506/edit ) your post to add (properly formatted) results, please. Don't respond with "Add Comment"